# php_memcache not working on my localhost wamp

Tags: php, wamp

Im running php 5.3.13 on wamp and I added my php_memcache.dll file, have this line in my php.ini file: `extension=php_memcache.dll` and in my wamp controller, under php extentions, php memcache is seleted.

I run this code:

```
<?php

  $memcache = new Memcache;
  $memcache->connect("127.0.0.1",8150); # You might need to set "localhost" to "127.0.0.1"
  echo "Server's version: " . $memcache->getVersion() . "<br />\n";
  $tmp_object = new stdClass;
  $tmp_object->str_attr = "test";
  $tmp_object->int_attr = 123;
  $memcache->set("key",$tmp_object,false,10);
  echo "Store data in the cache (data will expire in 10 seconds)<br />\n";
  echo "Data from the cache:<br />\n";
  var_dump($memcache->get("key"));

?>
```

and got this error:

```
Fatal error: Class 'Memcache' not found in memcacheTest.php on line 3
```

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Probably you already did but did you restart apache after editing php.ini?

Comment: yes, but I did notice in my php error log when I restart apache this warning: `PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'c:/wamp/bin/php/php5.3.13/ext/php_memcache.dll' - %1 is not a valid Win32 application.`

Comment: Do you have memcache running on your Windows server?

Answer (score 0):

if you are running windows8.1 x64, Just found a working solution, after digging a while :p

Hope that'll do the trick for you :)

http://www.anindya.com/php-5-4-3-and-php-5-3-13-x64-64-bit-for-windows/
Or directly on mediafire :
http://www.mediafire.com/php-win64-extensions

Search there for your version.